# Php Regex Between in Textnot working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I´m getting data with

```
$newtext = fread($rcon, 102400);
```

But this script is not working

```
$offset = stripos($newtext, 'ÿ');
```

But if i print it i could see the y

```
EYî ÿ5aa68
```

Why is it not working? Its kind of wired.. Because .. It is there..^^

Thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: Try: `$answer .= preg_replace ('/BE(.*?)ÿ/u' , '' , $newtext);`

Comment: You want to delete "BE" or the whole line?

Comment: I Want to delete everything between BE and y

Comment: '/BE(.*?)ÿ/u' didn´t worked.. It didnt add something to $answer

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($newtext);` in your question.

Comment: It is working [**here**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/nyw7-k065)

Comment: We may have to see the code around the line you provided.

Comment: $answer = fread($rcon, 102400);
  $answer = preg_replace ('/BE(.*)ÿ/','',$answer);

More?I think this is the important part

Comment: @Architect I think your question must be edited and/or closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer .= preg_replace ('/(BE.*?)ÿ/' , '' , $newtext);
```

or if you only want to remove between codes:

```
$answer .= preg_replace ('/BE(.*?)ÿ/' , '' , $newtext);
```

You can play tested here (expand SUBSTITUTION TAB): http://regex101.com/r/tO1aB8/1

Comment: They could be in a text to like this: " 38.254:23BE;ãjhÿ04 "
It didnt find something..

Comment: Why a dot before the equal sign? What contains `$answer`?

Comment: @Architect what is the output desired for 38.254:23BE;ãjhÿ04 input?

Comment: I´m writing a UPD communication tool
`$count = strToHex(substr($answer, 10, 1));
   echo $count."<br/>";
   for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++){
    $newtext = fread($rcon, 102400);
    $answer .= preg_replace ('/(BE.*?)ÿ/' , '' , $newtext);
    
   }
`
And the first $answer sends something like: "BE4" so the $count knows how often he has to listen.
Does it makes sense? :D

Comment: @Architect: No, Why a function named `strToHex` should return an int? What is this function?

Comment: Leandro's pattern is obviously ok (or with a u modifier) the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pwa9ivz0 my whole code... :( Thank you guys for helping me ! :)

Comment: Yes @CasimiretHippolyte.

Comment: @Architect: `$count` in your code sample is an hexadecimal **string**, you can't use it as an **int**.

Comment: Okay... What do i have to change? Im pretty new to these things.. I´m trying to learn it :) I tried this one: $count = intval(strToHex(substr($answer, 10, 1))); in line 87

Comment: @Architect: Sorry but I really don't know what you are trying to do!